# Adding a video to a Level in a Portal 2 Mod

Tags: modding, video, source-engine, valve, hammer

I'm currently working on my Portal 2 mod and I'd like to add a video to be displayed on a projector like [the Dollar$ and SENSE video at the end of Portal 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_PWxE3eZYU). Currently what I have is a simple recreation of a room in The Fall chapter of Portal 2, and I want to have a video displayed on the projection screen.

[image: My Map]

If anyone could give me instructions, or point me a link on how to do this that would be great.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to use an animated texture or [vgui_movie_display](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Vgui_movie_display).

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: Not exactly much to elaborate here, place the vgui_movie_display, fill out KeyValues, done.